# Is there a way to show multtiple integrals without using muliple integral symbols or the I symbol? Also can we say the -1 derivative is the integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, notation, indefinite-integrals

How do I show multiple integrals (20th integral)?

Can I use the -1 derivative to show an integral?

Can I use the -1 integral ( if its symbol exists) to show a derivative?

Comment: Depends how many integrations you need to carry out, I've never seen any need beyond four integral signs but you could consider $n$ integrations as $$\left( \displaystyle \int\right)^n$$

Comment: If the distinction between your iterated integral and the corresponding multi-dimensional integral isn't important in your case, you can write e.g. $\int\mathrm dxf(x)$ (where $x$ is a $20$-dimensional vector). (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Mathematical_definition).)